# After creating a custom theme in Magento 2 give an error in backend

Tags: magento2, theme-overriding

Why does it gives an error if I just created my custom theme in **Magento**, besides 
this there is only one custom module and nothing else, where does this error comes from?

And gives an error when I call the command setup:upgrade

> Module 'Magento_Theme': Running data recurring...Item
>   (Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data) with the same ID "0" already exists.

theme.xml

```
 <theme xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Config/etc/theme.xsd">
<title>Dataworld</title>
  <parent>Magento/blank</parent>
   <!-- <media>
      <preview_image>media/preview.jpg</preview_image>
   </media>-->
</theme>
```

registration.php

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
 \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::THEME,
'frontend/Shooga/Dataworld',
__DIR__
);
```

Comment: did you made your theme according to [this guidelines](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/theme-create.html)?

Comment: ABHISHEK TRIPATHI yes

Comment: Can u share the code from registration.php and theme.xml?

Comment: ABHISHEK TRIPATHI, edited my code

Comment: Check the theme table on database. It seems you have two theme_id with id of 0.

Comment: Check your theme id in theme table.