# After creating a custom theme , 2 same theme are inserted into the theme table and give an error, why?

Tags: magento2

After creating a custom theme , 2 same theme are inserted into the theme table and give an error

> Item (Magento\Theme\Model\Theme\Data) with the same ID "0" already exists.

Please help me

[image]

Comment: try to drop one of the duplicated rows and then in core_config_data set the theme_id according to your theme.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [After creating a custom theme in Magento 2 give an error in backend](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/263798/after-creating-a-custom-theme-in-magento-2-give-an-error-in-backend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this table your primary key constrain is failed. and same for auto increment.

make `theme_id` field as primary_key and auto increment and it will solve your problem